# Java: iterator from TreeMap entry?

Tags: java, containers, treemap

In Java, `TreeMap<K,V>` uses a RB-tree to store entries, allowing for in-order iteration using `map.entrySet().iterator()`, while guaranteeing insertion and lookup in log(N) time.

TreeMap also provides methods to find upper and lower bounds for a given key: `map.floorEntry(k)`, `map.ceilingEntry()`, `map.lowerEntry(k)` and `map.higherEntry()`. However, the return value of those is a `Map.Entry<K,V>` instance and won't directly allow one to visit neighbouring entries. I wanted to visit would-be neighbours of an hypothetical entry given its key.

Is there a way to get an iterator from a TreeMap entry or do what I'm trying to do?

Being more accustomed to C++'s `std::map<K,V>` class, I'm at a loss here...

**NOTE** I'm open to a solution using a container library other than java.util's as long as it has a sorted map container with some reasonable time complexity guarantees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the key of returned `Map.Entry<K, V>` as a parameter in `tailMap(K fromKey)` or `headMap(K toKey)`, and iterate the result.

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for; however, considering that I want to get both the entries that are immediately before and immediately after a given key, I would have to call both methods, meaning two lookups, which seems like a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: OK, sorry I misunderstood your answer, you obviously meant `map.tailMap(map.lowerEntry(k).getKey())`. That would work but still requires 2 lookups.

Comment: Another solution - made your own iterator of the TreeMap for your needs, but it's not an easy task